# Split string based on digits occurring from behind in Typescript based on regex group

Tags: javascript, regex, string, typescript, split

I am trying to split a string which is of the following format -

text = "some random words 22 minutes go some text that follows". I am only concerned about "some random words".

The text can have 'minute' or 'hour' or 'hours' in it. I want to split and get the string that is before the digits. I cannot split based on digits only because the initial part can have digits too.

I tried to handle this with split and if conditions. But those are not fast enough. I am struggling to deal this with typescript regex group. Any suggestions would be very helpful

The function that I used was -

```
export function splitstring(msg: string): string 
{
  if (msg.includes('minute')) 
  {
    return msg.toLowerCase().split('minute')[0];
  }
  if (msg.includes('minutes')) 
  {
    return msg.toLowerCase().split('minutes')[0];
  }
  if (msg.includes('hour')) 
  {
    return msg.toLowerCase().split('hour')[0];
  }
  if (msg.includes('hours')) 
  {
    return msg.toLowerCase().split('hours')[0];
  }
  return msg;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you can use `.match(/(.*)\W\d+\W(minute|hour)/)[1]`

```js
var text = "some random words 22 minutes go some text that follows";
console.log(
    text.match(/(.*)\W\d+\W(minute|hour)/)[1]
)

var text = "some random words 22 inute go some 12 hours text that follows";
console.log(
    text.match(/(.*)\W\d+\W(minute|hour)/)[1]
)

var text = "some 18 random words 22 minutes go 11 some text that follows";
console.log(
    text.match(/(.*)\W\d+\W(minute|hour)/)[1]
)
```